# itemWidget not moving along with list item?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4

I've set a custom widget to my list item, I want to move the list items..but when I do takeItem..the custom widget associated with the list item disappears and doesn't move along.

Edit

To add widget to the list item..

```
list_item = QtGui.QListWidgetItem()
list_widget = AdvancedScriptItem(numbered_name) #custom widget
self.ui.script_list.addItem(list_item)
self.ui.script_list.setItemWidget(list_item, list_widget)
```

To move an item I do..

```
list_item = self.ui.script_list.takeItem(row)
self.ui.script_list.insertItem(row - step, list_item)
```

Comment: Please show your code, please

Comment: I've added the code @eyllanesc

Comment: You have to call `self.ui.script_list.setItemWidget(list_item, list_widget)` after inserting. You will have to keep a reference to list_widget if you want to re-insert the same widget instance.